# When the Zariski topology is $T_1$ (depending on $k \ge 1)$.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, zariski-topology

Please explain when the Zariski topology is $T_1$ (depending on $k \ge 1$).

Let $X$ be a topological space and let $x$ and $y$ be points in $X$. We say that $x$ and $y$ are separated if each lies in a neighbourhood that does not contain the other point.

$X$ is called a $T_1$ space if any two distinct points in $X$ are separated.

Definition of Zariski topology on any field $\mathbb{K}^k$: has as closed sets $V(J)$, where we hvae that $J \subseteq \mathbb{K}[x_1,...,x_k]$ an ideal.

I don't know when the Zariski topology is $T_1$ (depending on $k \ge 1$).

Comment: This essentially never happens. If $C$ is an irreducible component of $X$ then $C=\overline{\{x\}}$ for some point $x$, but since $X$ is $T_1$ points are closed, so $C=\{x\}$. As $X$ is the union of its irreducible components, each of which is closed, so if it has only finitely many such irreducible components (which happens if $X$ is, say, finite type over a field) then each will be open (as they are now disjoint). Thus, $X$ is discrete. In general, you can have rings whose spectrum is a highly non-trivial pro-finite space, but this doesn't happen for things locally of finite type over fields

Comment: I am not familiar with algebraic geometry, but I think in Affine n-space, the Zariski topology is always $T_1$. It is because every point $\{(a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_n)\}$ is a zero set of the ideal $\langle x_1-a_1, x_2-a_2, \cdots, x_n-a_n\rangle$, which is closed.

Comment: Could you  give me answer... Becuase I think that I donn't understnad evrything...  Please... And thank you for your conversation.  @AlexYoucis

Comment: Or  @MichaelWeiss? Please becuase i would like to know about it

Comment: @MichaelWeiss I answered assuming that these were schemes, not classical 'pre-varieties'. So, for instance, $\mathbb{A}^n_\mathbb{K}=\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{K}[x_1,\ldots,x_n])$ contains the non-closed point $(0)$. It seems this is not what the OP is interested in.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible answers to your question: the classical answer, and the more modern Grothendieck answer.

First, the classical answer: the Zariski topology is $T_1$. A point is always closed, because $\{(a_1,\ldots,a_k)\}$ is the zero set of the ideal $(x_1-a_1,\ldots,x_k-a_k)$. $T_1$ is equivalent to saying all points are closed, so the space is $T_1$.

Grothendieck and his collaborators reformulated algebraic geometry; this is sometimes called the "scheme revolution". Part of this recasting involved generalizing the notion of "point" to include all irreducible components. This may seem strange, but I'll suggest briefly the motivation below. The closure of a "point" now becomes the set of all irreducible components contained in it. With this definition, the answer is typically no. Two lines (regarded as "points") that intersect in a classical point cannot be separated, because their closures intersect in the classical point.

Why this expanded notion of "point"? Well, even classically we have the correspondence between ideals and algebraic sets. Recall that this is order-reversing. Let's restrict to the classical case where the ground field $\mathbb{K}$ is algebraically closed. The space of all classical points corresponds to MaxSpec, the maximal spectrum, which is the collection of all maximal ideals.
The closed sets in the Zariski topology on MaxSpec are of the form $\{M\in\text{MaxSpec}\;|\;M\supseteq I\}$, where $I$ is an ideal.

It turns out the prime spectrum Spec has nicer properties than the maximal spectrum.  This is especially true when we want to generalize beyond the classical case of an algebraically closed ground field. We define the Zariski topology on Spec just the same way: the closed sets are things of the form $\{P\in\text{Spec}\;|\;P\supseteq I\}$, where $I$ is an ideal.

Translating back using the order-reversing correspondence, the switch from MaxSpec to Spec means we should consider all irreducible components to be "points" of the space.

Caveat: If you glance at the Wikipedia entry for "schemes", you will see I've barely hinted at all the complexities of the Grothedieck approach. I've tried to say just enough to answer your question.

Comment: But I found it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ (The Zariski topology on $Spec(R)$, the prime spectrum of a commutative ring $R$, is always $T_0$ but generally not $T_1$. ) I know that we consider field... It not depends on k? Why? @michael wiess

Comment: The issue is, the Zariski topology of what? Your original question asked about the ZT of affine $k$-space. This is always $T_1$. We can also ask about the ZT of Spec(R), or of maxSpec(R) (the space of maximal ideals). For an *algebraically closed* field $k$, there is a close relation betwen maxSpec(k) and affine $k$-space; the result is that the ZT of maxSpec(k) is also always $T_1$. Finally, for Spec(R), or even for Spec(k), even with $k$ algebraically closed, the ZT is typically not $T_1$ but only $T_0$. This last is what Alex was talking about (the "Grothendieck viewpoint").